# Reading multiple data types and sizes from .txt in C++

Tags: c++, input

I have the following input text file:

```
MISSISSIPPI

0 1 5 6

3

0 1 1 1,
0 1 4 4,
0 0 0 1,
0 0 0 2,
1 1 1 1,
0 1 1 1
```

I want to read the first string, 2nd line array, 3rd integer, and then the remaining entire matrix, into 4 variables respectively. How can I do this?

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with a `std::ifstream`.

The 1st line is simple enough, just use `std::getline()` to read the entire line into a `std::string`.

If the 2nd line is always 4 integers, you could just hard-code 4 calls to `operator>>`, storing the values into an `int[4]` array.  But, a more robust solution would be to first read the line entire using `std::getline()`, then create a `std::istringstream` from the `std::string`, and then call `operator>>` in a loop to read the integers from the stream, storing them into a dynamic array like `std::vector`.

The 3rd line is simple enough, just use `operator>>`.

Finally, for the matrix, that is similar to the 2nd line above.  Since you now know how to parse multiple integers from 1 line, just do that over and over for multiple lines, either in a loop until there are no more lines to read, or a hard-coded number of iterations if the matrix is fixed-sized.

Comment: I would say use `getline()` for _all_ input lines: the 3rd line is just a case of a single-element array, which OP’s code could then treat as a single integer input.